# Browse entire file system in "browse" dialog box?

Tags: file-system, file-management, files

I am trying to use KeePassDroid and when I select the browse button for the keyfile section it shows this screen:

[image]

As you can see, it's only limited to "Recent, Images, Videos, Audio, Downloads". My key file is located elsewhere and can't be located from these options.

How can I browse the entire file system and bypass these predefined options?

Comment: Try installing this app. It worked for me from 6.0 to 8.0 in such situations https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ianhanniballake.localstorage

Comment: @beeshyams that appears to work but it seems it can only access the SD card, do you know if it's also possible to access phone storage?

Comment: In my case it accesses all - External SD, phone storage, videos, audio, connected  Google Drives, downloads, audio and video and also has a section on for recently accessed locations. Open the app and tap the button that says something like *show all files*- I used this on Moto X Play running Marshmallow and MiA1 running Oreo. I don't use keep pass so can't say about that but it works for all apps I use

Comment: On the 3dot menu on top right, click and see if there is an option to *show internal storage*

Comment: @beeshyams there's no 3dot menu, just sort menu as seen in the screenshot